# prepareForSegue and setting property setting

Tags: uitableview, ios5, properties, storyboard, segue

I have a UITableViewController that displays cells that are just default. Each cell can be touched and taken to a list that is within the "account" that each cell in the first view holds.

I connected everything up with a segue and then in my first view I call:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Account *nextAccount = [self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *viewController = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        viewController.account = nextAccount;
    } 
}
```

and then in the detail view's viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated I say:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
self.list = [self.account.list mutableCopy];
}
```

and then I have a UITableViewController on the detail view but in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method I access the self.list but it doesn't seem to be working. I know my cellForRowAtIndexPath: works because earlier I did some template work with the method and it worked fine. It seems to be just the prepareForSegue: isn't working or the property isn't being set.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably trying to set up the detail table view long before viewDidAppear is called. Instead try overriding the setter for the data model:

```
-(void)setList:(List*)list    // or whatever type list is
{
    if (_list != list) {
        _list = [list mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

Then it should create the copy before the view is loaded.

Also if you're going to override viewDidAppear, be sure to call the super:

```
[super viewDidAppear];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSLog and do a check to see if each element != nil. (nextAccount, etc.) Objective C will happily let you send messages to nil objects without throwing an error msg.

Also put a log statement in your segue conditional statement to make sure it is getting called.